# Realm 50k files convert into 100 sections

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a situation where I got 50k DB files I need to group them into 100 sections.

I am doing like below, which is causing memory issues. are there any alternatives.

```
var numberOfRows:Array<Int> = [0] // This array I am using

for sectionName in sectionKeys {
    let count = realmResults.filter("%K == %@", self.getSectionNameKeyPath(), sectionName).count
    numberOfRows[index] = count
    index += 1
}
```